# List users/passwords and session accounts in Windows 7 and 8

Tags: windows, windows-8

On Windows 7 and 8, which commands list all users/passwords and session accounts? Is it possible to query all active accounts?

Answer (score 0):

In a shell, enter the following commands:

```
net user
net session
net /?

"%programfiles%\intern~1\iexplore.exe http://www.apple.com
```

Comment: do not show current user accounts/logins/passwords in my laptop :/

Comment: @Anthony It will show everything but passwords, right?

Comment: yes list users and passwords